# Remove turtle from chest boat without breaking the boat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a chest boat parked at a village, far away from what I thought looked like a beach. But in the short time I've been in the village, a turtle has decided to get in the boat. Breaking the boat loses everything in the chest, which I then have to collect, but have no place to put because finding the boat as the first entity is unlikely.

I have leads, but leads do not seem to attach to the turtle. This is frustrating and broken mechanics. Is there any way to remove the turtle from my boat without breaking the boat? Do I need to change my gameplay style, and murder turtles on sight before I step out of the boat? Is there a mod for it that spreads a virus among all turtles in the game, torturing them to death?

Comment: Pressing F3+B shows you if there is really no tiny bit of hitbox left to hit the boat. Technically you could spam more boats around your boat to catch all turtles before they get to it, but I have a feeling that that is not the best option. :D

Comment: https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-125892

Comment: The part requesting for a mod falls under recommendation, you may want to remove that question

Answer (score 3):

### If the boat is in water (most likely scenario).

If you have a trapdoor and create a flow to push the boat against it, you can drop a sand block on top of the trapdoor and suffocate the turtle.
[image: A setup depicting how to suffocate a turtle.]

### If the boat is on land.

You can eject any entity by pouring water on the boat.
[image: A turtle and a boat underwater. Note that the turtle can't enter the boat.]
*You don't need this much water. This is just for ease of visibility.*
The turtle won't drown because it is aquatic.

Comment: Technically this does answer my question. But sort of misses the point of it... this boat is no longer sailable, and I'd have to break it and refloat it, complete with the full chest. And if it happens anywhere but shallow water, it's worse than just chopping it with the axe. Updooting for effort though.

Comment: Place blocks. Then place the water, move the turtle (or murder it if you want to), and then remove the water. The blocks are so the boat doesn't go anywhere. Wait I realize my mistake. My example was on land. No idea why I thought that would be the case.

Comment: If you have a piston and redstone on available, you could push the boat out of the water. Or if you have soul sand you can use a bubble column.

Comment: I have amended my answer.